# Sonarqube saying "String literal expressions should be on the left side of an equals comparison" for non-String types

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm using Sonarqube to analyze my Java code, and I'm getting several issues with the message:

> String literal expressions should be on the left side of an equals comparison

This is easy to solve with strings, flipping the order to avoid possible `NullPointerException`s

```
//From this:
myString.equals("otherString");

//To this:
"otherString".equals(myString);
```

However, I'm having these problems with non-String types, such as in the following code:

```
if (myObject.getIntegerAttribute.equals(1)){ // <-Sonarqube shows the issue here
    // ...
}
```

Since I can't flip the "1" as it is a primitive type and doesn't have an `equals()` method, how can I solve these issues?

Comment: Problem is that you are not checking null in first case. For integer there auto boxing, you can turn it to `Integer.valueOf(1).equals(...)` if you really want to do object comparison...

Comment: Trusting Sonar is appreciable, if this is not mission critical project I'd not touch the code to fix sonar issue, as @Belista suggest using a null check is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the issue by explicitely boxing the `int` into an `Integer`:

```
if (Integer.valueOf(1).equals(myObject.getIntegerAttribute)) { // <-- explicit box
    // ...
}
```

This will handle correctly the case where `myObject.getIntegerAttribute` is `null` by returning `false`.

Note that this does not create any overhead: declaring `Integer value = 1` compiles to `Integer value = Integer.valueOf(1)`. Note also that since this value (1) is cached, it will not actually create a new `Integer` object.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer test = 1;
if ( test.equals(myObject.getIntegerAttribute())
```

should help fix your issue. Then again: is it really worth storing a local variable?

```
if ( Integer.valueOf(1).equals(myObject.getIntegerAttribute())
```

might be an improvement.

Since you can configure the sonar rules yourself, it's hard to say which one 'll best according your configuration.

Comment: Creating a new object to solve a sonar issue sounds silly to me

Comment: @Shiva: indeed, which is why I added the remark in the answer myself, and a better proposal

Comment: @Shiva Actually, this does not create a new object since 1 is cached, see my answer.

Comment: @Tunaki: for an example, I added as first example one where I did create a new Object, followed by the question: is it worth it. I assume he means that one

Comment: In both cases, no new object is allocated (`Integer test = 1;` is equivalent to `Integer test = Integer.valueOf(1);`, see my answer).

Comment: @Tunaki it does if it is not cached already. Interger.value only offers an alternative but no guarantee that a new object won't be created. Anyway IMHO we are going off topic.

Comment: it does create a new local variable, if not 'really used' sonar might complain about it. I'm aware that an Integer has a limited set of values and they're not "renewed", but it's the reference he talks about